# Square Roots with Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

I learned about Square roots and with exponents, but not this:

The radius $r$ in millimeters of a platinum wire $L$ centimeters long with resistance $0.1$ ohm is $r = 0.059L^\frac 12$. How long is a wire with a radius of $0.236$ millimeter?

Comment: Substitute 0.236 for r in your formula then divide both sides by 0.059. Finally, square both sides to get rid of the 1/2 exponent [power-to-a-power, multiply exponents], this yields an exponent on L of 1.

Answer (score 0):

$$.236=.059L^{\frac{1}{2}}=.059\sqrt{L}$$

and then solve as you would any simple equation